# Element (UL) over flowing parent (DIV)

Tags: padding

I have been battling to find an answer to this, I don't know whether I am just bad at searching or what, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Basically I have a DIV called 'menu' (#menu) and it's a blue bar that stretches across the top of the browser screen, in it I have set up an unordered list (to create buttons) and for the anchors (hyperlinks) inside the list to have padding (for the sake of the text being spaced nicely) and therefore create a beautiful button, however, when I do this, hyperlink causes the line to flow over the menu div, making it look messy, below is my code, is there anyway to prevent this?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { font-family: Helvetica; }
body { margin: 0; background: #fff; }
#menu { overflow: inline-block; width: 100%; background: #0b9be5; text-align: center; }
#menu ul { background: #075f8d;  poistion: absolute; margin: 0px; list-style-type: none; }
#menu li { display: inline; }
#menu a { padding: 1%;  border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; color: black;     text-decoration: none; }
#menu a:hover { background-color: #0b9be5; }
```

Thank you in advance!

Kind Regards

Matthew

Comment: Check your spelling in the property #menu ul poistion. I will correct you in the post. It is useful this website http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

Answer (score 0):

I have done a totally new code for you!

I recommend you to check this web site http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/ for more options.

The CSS is like this

```
.menu-menu-container{
    position: absolute;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    border:#996600 1px solid;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
li a{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #00F;
    display: block;
    padding:20px;
}
a:hover{
    background:#33FFFF;
}
```

And the HTML could be like this

```
<div class="menu-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143"><a href="http://origenes.co">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a href="http://origenes.co/corporativo/">Corporativo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: for me, display:block makes the elements take up the entire page width and therefore make it so each hyperlink takes up a line.